Prior art on precedence rules on template instantiation for inner entity clashes
I'm looking for prior art on languages handling clashes happening during template instantiation between inner entities. For example, if we have a type parameter E intended to be an exception type and a catch block within that scope like that:
try {...} catch E { /*a*/ } catch Exception { /*b*/ }

How would existing languages handle the situation if E is instantiated with Exception?
A similar example could be made with int-typed parameters and common switch case if the parameter were allowed to be a case label:
switch (...) { case E: /*a*/ case 7: /*b*/ }

Note: This is not about overload resolution. It is about precedence or conflict rules when eliminating code during template substitution.
Note: My current understanding of the situation is that it only makes sense in λ polymorphism. For ∀ polymorphism like Java generics, the resolution would always happen before any substitution happens irrespective of the actual language.

I'm struggling to think of a valid use case where this wouldn't just be an error...

@CoffeeTableEspresso if you know a widely used language where it is an error, I'd appreciate the answer. Error was one of the options I thought about. Still, my current favorite is a bit more complex than that.

In C#, it's not an error. If E is Exception, then the first catch gets executed:
void F<E>() where E : Exception, new()
{
    try
    {
       if (new Random().Next() % 2 == 0)
           throw new E();
       else
           throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (E)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("E");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception");
    }
}
F<Exception>();

always prints E.
However, if you were to put the Exception catch before the E catch, you would get
error CS0160: A previous catch clause already catches all exceptions of this or of a super type ('Exception')
Now that you mention it, I think this situation could be worth a warning, or a lint?
But I've never used an exception type as a generic type parameter, so it's a bit of a theoretical question to me.

Now, for a switch on types:
int G<E>(object o) => o switch
    {
        E => 1,
        Exception => 2,
        _ => 3,
    };
Console.WriteLine(G<Exception>(new Exception()));

This prints 1.
Similarly, if you put the Exception case before E and you add where E : Exception, then you get:
error CS8510: The pattern is unreachable. It has already been handled by a previous arm of the switch expression or it is impossible to match.

I only noticed myself because for exception handlers, as you say, the behavior starts to matter and is somewhat strange. For switch case, apparently I just picked randomly all the time and never noticed. For me, it's more a consistency thing as I cannot remember ever having encountered it.
